# Find end of characters in a string

Tags: c, caesar-cipher

I'm writing a caesar cipher, which shifts the value of each char in an array by a set amount. The issue I'm having is that the char values after my string are being shifted as well. *I'm hoping to ignore these values entirely/not print them.*

I have the following which compiles below, but I can't think of how to not parse trailing chars as well. My encrypt function **must** take these exact parameters, so I cannot pass the length to it as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void encrypt(char *message, int shift);

int main(void)
{
    int shift_amount;
    int length;
    char message[80];
    char c;

    printf("Enter message to be encrypted: ");
    for (length = 0; ( c = getchar()) != '\n'; length++) {
        message[length] = c;
    }

    printf("Enter shift amount (1-25): ");
    scanf("%d", &shift_amount);

    encrypt(message, 3);

    return 0;
}

void encrypt(char *message, int shift){
    printf("Encrypted message: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++) {
        char ch = message[i];

        if (message[i] >= 'a' && message[i] <= 'z') {
            ch = (( ch - 'a' ) + shift) % 26 + 'a';
        } else if (message[i] >= 'A' && message[i] <= 'Z') {
            ch = (( ch - 'A' ) + shift) % 26 + 'A';
        }
        printf("%c", ch);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

An desired example input/output would be:

input: "Go ahead, make my day." with shift of 3

output: "Jr dkhdg, pdnh pb gdb."

Thank you!

Comment: You should null terminate the string you read, and you should stop processing when you reach the null byte terminating the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of modifying exactly 80 characters, just stop when you reach the end of the string. How do you tell when the end of the string is? Because the first character after the end of the string will be the string terminator, i.e. `'\0'`.

In your code you can do that by replacing the `for` condition, from `i<80` to `message[i] != '\0'`, or using both conditions if you want to specify a maximum length as well, just to be sure.

As I realize now your string does not have a terminator at all. You should put one when you read the characters from the console:

```
printf("Enter message to be encrypted: ");
for (length = 0; ( c = getchar()) != '\n'; length++) {
    message[length] = c;
}
message[length] = '\0'; // <- add this here
```

Comment: The `i<80` is needed in the `for (length = 0;...` loop more so than the `for (int i = 0;...` loop.

Comment: @chux actually in that loop you should stop at `i < 79` because you need one space to add the `'\0'` terminator (see edit). Strings in C need 1 more byte for terminator after all the characters - otherwise as you experimented it is not possible to determine when they end

Comment: You can add that condition as such: `(c = getchar()) != '\n' && length < 79`

Comment: @pqnet The program seems to compile fine without, what role does the terminator fill? I don't doubt its importance.

Comment: @rborum a lot of programs do compile fine, but do not do what you expect them to do. In particular, in unsafe languages like C compiler won't complain about a lot of things that are indeed wrong, mostly because the compiler expect you to know what you are doing. You can indeed put the characters without terminator, but you would need to keep track of the length of the string in some other way, otherwise you wouldn't be able to distinguish the characters that you wrote in there from the garbage that might have been already there.

Comment: @rborum Using the `'\0'` terminator is the standard C way to mark the end of a string, it is also the way the standard C library functions such as `strcpy` `strlen` `printf("%s")` expect you to use.